# How to color lines in Epilog

Tags: graphics, color

I often use Epilog to label lines within graphs, and I like to coordinate the color of the labels with the color of the lines they're labeling. This is no problem. However, I'm currently working on a project in which I need vertical connecting lines at selected places, and these should color match as well. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x + 0.5]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Epilog -> {
   Line[{{2, 0}, {2, Sin[2]}}],
   Line[{{3, 0}, {3, Sin[3.5]}}]}]
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
   Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x + 0.5]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, Line[{{2, 0}, {2, Sin[2]}}], Red, 
   Line[{{3, 0}, {3, Sin[3.5]}}]}]
```

Answer (score 10):

kguler's method gets the job done but in anything but the simplest uses it can become a headache.

In cases like this I prefer to use either a custom plot function or a function/rule that accepts plot output and applies my changes automatically.  For example:

```
addEpilog[g_Graphics, epi_List] :=
  With[{styles = Cases[g[[1]], {dir__, __Line} :> Directive[dir], -5]},
    Show[g, Epilog -> {styles, epi} ~Flatten~ {2}]
  ]
```

Now:

```
p = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x + 0.5]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}];

addEpilog[p,
  { Line[{{2, 0}, {2, Sin[2]}}], Line[{{3, 0}, {3, Sin[3.5]}}] }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To add multiple primitives in a given style simply group them in a `List`:

```
addEpilog[p,
 {
  Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Sin[#]}}] &      /@ {2, 4, 6},
  Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Sin[# + .5]}}] & /@ {1, 3, 5}
 }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]